# is there react based tooltip solution that does not depends on target id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, tooltip, bootstrap-4

for example, [reactstrap's tooltip component](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/) if no target id defined or even by using random generated id, it cause document error like
`index.js:16 Error: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '7fHjA78731291' is not a valid selector.` Also it cause bug for Jest unit test when we are dealing with snapshots testing. However, [they seems not consider there is a solution to fix it.](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/818)

I wonder why there are not a tooltip component build with react that actually has no dependency on id for its label dom? I saw several other tooltip solution, all of them depends on id.. why can't we just leave the id alone?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the code how you implemented the tooltip?

Comment: Id is used for accessibilty purposes. When you define an icon which triggers show of actual tooltip text that user can read, the text in tooltip is referenced from hidden element. Read more about it here: http://accessibility.athena-ict.com/aria/examples/tooltip.shtml

Comment: @Shota what I try to do is almost identical to the tooltip's example, but without wanting to reference id

Comment: @PawełMikołajczyk but if it missing, error also cames up, so not just accessibility for sure

Comment: Well, you don't even need Javascript to create a custom tooltip, take a look at this for example: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Comment: @Shota awesome! silly me... plz put it as the answer, I will +1. thanks